# How to execute shell commands from within a Kubernetes ConfigMap?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, aws-secrets-manager

I am using Helm charts to create and deploy applications into my K8s cluster.

One of my pods requires a config file with a SDK key to start and function properly. This SDK key is considered a secret and is stored in AWS Secret Manager. I don't include the secret data in my Docker image. I want to be able to mount this config file at runtime. A ConfigMap seems to be a good option in this case, except that I have not been able to figure out how to obtain the SDK key from Secrets Manager during the chart installation. Part of my ConfigMap looks like this:

```
   data:
      app.conf: |
      [sdkkey] # I want to be able to retrieve sdk from aws secrets manager
```

I was looking at ways to write shell commands to use AWS CLI to get secrets, but have not seen a way to execute shell commands from within a ConfigMap.

Any ideas or alternative solutions?

Cheers
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*tl;dr;* You can't execute a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/), it is just a static manifest. Use an [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) instead.

ConfigMaps are a static manifest that can be read from the Kubernetes API or injected into a container at runtime as a file or environment variables. There is no way to execute a ConfigMap.

Additionally, ConfigMaps should not be used for secret data, Kubernetes has a specific resource, called [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/), to use for secret data. It can be used in similar ways to a ConfigMap, including being mounted as a volume or exposed as environment variables within the container.

Given your description it sounds like your best option would be to use an [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to retrieve the credentials and write them to a shared [emptyDir Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) mounted into the container with the application that will use the credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i was looking into init containers, but got distracted when I read that cofigmaps are intended to be able to inject configuration files into the container.

Comment: Slightly different question, since am using can i not use the templating power within helm to execute a sh command and use the output as the text to configmap?

Comment: You could, but the issue is that the lifecycle of the credentials would be tied to you running a `helm install` or `helm upgrade`, and would require you to have tooling installed locally on every machine that would interact with the chart. 
By retrieving the credentials from an initContainer the cluster would be able to resolve issues when the credentials are changed by retrieving a new set via the AWS secret manager

Comment: Agreed with the dependency on the tooling part. I ask this because I dont have the liberty of modifying the chart itself (I just use it, by plugging in my values.yaml). The charts themselves currently support the use of configmaps but not initcontainers. Hence am pushing towards configmap.

Comment: You could also run a separate [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) to do a one-time update to the ConfigMap, a [CronJon](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) to do a scheduled update to the ConfigMap, or you can edit the chart by doing a `helm fetch` if you don't have the chart locally. If you have more specific questions, please ask me (@chaosaffe) on the Kubernetes Slack so I can give direct answers. If you find the answer satisfies the question, please accept it.
Thanks!

Comment: Is it a public chart? If so maybe you can raise a request to get a way to add the hook you want for an initContainer. You could also look at pod lifecycle hooks or a helm pre-install hook

Comment: Thanks a bunch for all the responses. I have decided to ask the chart creators to give us the ability to use initcontainers.@chaosaffe thanks for pointing out that configmap is a static manifest and cannot be used in my case